# Why didn't Voldemort drink unicorn blood in the final fight?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

We all know that the person who drinks unicorn blood shall be kept alive even in the most dreadful situations. So why didn't Voldemort drink unicorn blood in the final fight? It could have kept him alive!

Comment: There is a lot of information here about why he wouldn't want to drink unicorn blood http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14795/what-sort-of-curse-does-unicorns-blood-give/83657#83657

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Short answer: When would he have?

Voldemort was sure he could finally kill Harry with the Elder Wand. In the forest, Harry did not even defend himself. So why would he drink Unicorn Blood now? He also still had an Horcurx left.

When Harry revealed that he was not dead, it was to late for Voldemort to do anything about it. And even in the final fight, he still was sure he could simply kill Harry, up to the moment he died.

And when his killing spell rebound and killed him instead, Voldemort was killed instantly. Without any Horcruxes left and killed by Avada Kedavra, his life was over, he was dead. Once and for all.

Comment: given the action sequence obviously, but we are talking about a man who is trying to do everything in his power to stay immortal, he tried to protect nagini, I agree with your point which says he assumed harry was dead, but do you think if he knew that harry had the elder wand, he would have done something like that?

Comment: Voldemort is extremely narcissistic. He is convinced that he is the most powerful wizard ever and that having seven horcruxes makes him absolutely invincible. He does not even bother hiding them properly (i.e. a single pebble amidst thousands of other pebbles would be a much better horcrux). So why would such an *immensely powerful wizard* bother with drinking unicorn blood when he already is invincible?

Comment: He did not just assume Harry was dead, he had Narcissa confirm it (and as Lars said, he was too blind to even see the possibility of her betraying him), and as Harry said to him, he didn't really listen to Olivander: he thought holding the Elder Wand and being the most powerful (and still having Nagini as a Horcrux) made him invincible. He would never think someone would even be remotely capable of being any real threat to him and his power - especially not since Dumbledore died.

Answer (score 1):

## Unicorn blood is a cure, not prevention.

Unicorn blood could revive someone who was an inch from death, but it’s never said to make the person who drinks it immune from future harm, even as a temporary effect. It just helps keep them from dying from what they were already dying from before they drank it.

> “Only one who has nothing to lose, and everything to gain, would commit such a crime. The blood of a unicorn will keep you alive, even if you are an inch from death, but at a terrible price. You have slain something pure and defenceless to save yourself and you will have but a half life, a cursed life, from the moment the blood touches your lips.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 15 (The Forbidden Forest)*</sup></sub>

Unicorn blood doesn’t protect against future causes of death. Quirrell had been drinking it for the Dark Lord for weeks.

> “Unicorn blood has strengthened me, these past weeks … you saw faithful Quirrell drinking it for me in the Forest …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)*</sup></sub>

However, Quirrell still died from the burns that touching Harry for so long while sharing his body with the Dark Lord caused him.

> “He is still out there somewhere, perhaps looking for another body to share … not being truly alive, he cannot be killed. He left Quirrell to die; he shows just as little mercy to his followers as his enemies.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17 (The Man with Two Faces)*</sup></sub>

The unicorn blood he drank hadn’t stopped him from dying, so would be similarly useless to the Dark Lord as a way to prevent his death.